# Is it possbile to conduct http header injection attack with a web site or web app uses https?

Tags: tls, web-application, http, injection, websites

If a web site or web application is running with https, is it possible to conduct http header attacks like http header injections and so on?

Comment: The header would be encrypted ...

Comment: Therefore one can say that it is impossible to do http header injection  or any other related http header attack on https right?

Comment: By a MitM, yes (assuming the TLS connection is secure, or course). It does nothing for broken clients, obviously.

Comment: @Coding_A_Nation Correct. If the attacker cannot downgrade the connection to HTTP, they cannot inject content.

Comment: that meanst you need to use https with HSTS http strick security transport to prevent downgrading attacks and MitM. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but only in certain cases.  There are two general classes of Header Injection attacks that I am aware of:

One is a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack where someone is intercepting your traffic to inject header info.  HTTPS connections protect against these.

The second is a Cross-Site Script (XSS) attack.  These are attacks against an application level vulnerability where a user of a website can use his input to affect the way that headers are dynamically created for other users. With XSS attacks, you change the way the server parses what it's sending you before it is encrypted for transmission; thus the content can be modified.

An example of this vulnerability might look like:

```
<?php
  ... // functions and SQL to collect $resultHeader and $resultHTML parameters from your database.
  $header = buildHeader($resultHeader); 
  $html = buildHTML($resultHTML);
  echo $header;
  echo $html;
?>
```

Since the buildHTML() function processes before the $header variable is written to the page, a PHP injection could rewrite $header before it is echoed.

Comment: How exactly does XSS "change the way the server parses what it's sending you"?

Comment: Most websites use a backend language such as PHP to build a page's HTML and JS.  A poorly validated system could allow a PHP injection to interfere with how the page's JS and HTML are assembled meaning that it can change the HTML header in the process of building the page.  Much like SQL injections, modern language standards and frameworks make XXS header attacks mostly a thing of the past, but you still sometimes get poorly built systems that don't explicitly declare their HTML headers before allowing user inputs to process.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about some sort of server-side code injection. XSS is client-side.

Comment: XSS can be both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392997/server-xss-vs-client-xss.  At its heart, an XSS attack is just an attack where one end user can inject code for another end user to execute.

Comment: AndrolGenhald if he is talking about server-side code injection that sounds like cross-site request forgery attack.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Server side XSS is still JavaScript that gets executed on the client. Code executed on the server is not XSS.

Comment: It's not a CSRF. That is where a malicious application is executed client-side to exploit other applications your browser is using.  An XSS attack is any attack that uses a vulnerable input to attack end users rather than the server itself. An HTML header is still executed client side; so, I don't see any reason to not to call this an XSS attack.  In general, a JS XSS attack is much more common than a PHP Header XSS attack, but the later allows you to do more things like modify the CSP which could be used to open up additional JS XSS vectors of attack.

Answer (score 0):

For all protocol level attacks, that is HTTP splitting and cache poisoning using headers injections via bad HTTP syntax parsing (**HTTP Smuggling**), the TLS protection would not protect you.
HTTP protocol is encapsulated in the TLD/SSL layer, but at the end the parser will read an HTTP message, as if no encryption was done. The TLS layer protects the message while it's traveling, not when an HTTP actor is parsing it.

At least the TLS adds some complexity on the attacker side, where a tool supporting TLS (like openssl_client) has to be used and not very simple socket connections tools like telnet or netcat. Nothing that cannot be done.

There is also headers injection via application errors, usually via **CRLF injections** on query arguments. Here again TLS protection adds very few protections.